# Why cannot I use silhouette score with ground truth labels?

Tags: clustering, feature-engineering

I was looking into checking cluster positioning from a non-liner transformation. I do have the ground truth labels. Now, I want to use the transformed data points and see how good this transformation is for original cluster labels. I do not want to deploy another clustering algorithm to cluster the data again. Basically I want to have a metric like this:

```
m_1 = metric(X,ground_truth)
m_2 = metric(f(X),ground_truth)
```

My initial thought was that using silhouette score with ground truth labels will be enough. But it seems that, in the literature, silhouette score is often attributed for predicted labels.

Is there any problem if I use silhouette score with ground truth labels for different transformation of the data?

Note: I'm sure that for clustering it is not ideal to use a score like that. But what I'm trying to do is not clustering. I already have the cluster labels. Now I just want to evaluate if I transform the data through some function how much of that clustering is preserved. So, I think my case is different than unsupervised clustering.

Comment: I don't see anything that's wrong with it.

Comment: I also thought the same. But since there was not much precedence I decided to ask here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, if you do that in a publication, it may well be that somebody questions it on the basis that hardly anybody else is doing it. So chances are you will have to make some more effort to explain it than if you did something that is very familiar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input!